# sqlalchemy reflection doesn't get a table

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to reflect one table in PGSQL, and it doesn't show. In fact there are many more tables not reflected, but I'm focusing on this one.

So it's the standard way here:

```
engine = create_engine(DATABASE_URI, echo='debug')
metadata=MetaData()
metadata.reflect(engine, only=['cw_products_history'])
Base = automap_base(metadata=metadata)
Base.prepare()
```

Here's what's printed by the sqlalchemy, apparently it sees the table, I see no cursing and nothing bad therein, but the table doesn't appear among the classes. https://pastebin.com/t9PL9Nk2

```
(Pdb) dir(Base.classes)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__get__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__self__', '__self_class__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__thisclass__']
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: Does the table have a primary defined?

Comment: Oh! I see it doesn't for some reason.

Comment: I think I've read something about primary keys issue, I don't remember what though:)

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/automap.html#basic-use

Comment: Yes, viable. Mind creating an answer? I think it may be worth having this question and this answer for the people that will come after. I got a SO hint, and read about specifying *echo* keyword in create_engine:)

Comment: I've answered it before :)

Comment: Ah! I see, it's linked. Thank you so much!